# VS2013 Debug/Windows/Tasks: "No tasks to display"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, task, visual-studio-debugging

I have Visual Studio Professional 2013 and I am debugging an application which uses async/await extensively. But when I stop at breakpoint and open Debug/Windows/Tasks window, it always says "No tasks to display."

I've made two test, in one I can see task, in another I can't (I run program, and pause it). Or I can breakpoint at waiting fro task line.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TasksDebugWindowTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoesNotWork();
        }

        static void Works()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(100 * 1000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Task complete");
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", t.Status);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", t.Status);
            t.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        static void DoesNotWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            var t = Task.Delay(100 * 1000);
            t.Wait();  // **** Breakpoint here
            Console.WriteLine("Task complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain why I can see tasks in one case but not in another?

Comment: It should show up, I created [a simple test program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mVHNSq) and when I look at my task view [it shows up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I2oIv.png) (this screenshot is from VS2013 Premium). Can you add a simple test program that replicates the problem and post it in your question [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26638563/edit)? Without a reproducible example your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks Scott, added the code, and manage to make it working in one case.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of it not working? Your "does not work example" works fine on my machine if I [hit pause during the wait](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jZyKP.png) or if I [use a breakpoint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZK5i.png)

Comment: Here it is, @ScottChamberlain:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rtAhmWT6bpN3NkSXlNY0JlVnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Very very strange. I just came home from work to try it out... and my home computer does not show the task.

Comment: I thought it might be a 4.5.1 vs 4.5.2 thing, but I just updated my home computer to build in 4.5.2 and it still does not show up. I have no idea why one works one one does not. You get a +1 and favorite from me, I am stumped.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, do you happen to have Win8.1 at work and Win7 at home?

Comment: Yes, yes I do... Interesting. If you look at the source for `DelayPromise` (the [internal class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,291b6f82d3bd29c1) `Task.Delay` is basically a wrapper for) the function `AddToActiveTasks(this);`, which I think is what puts the task on to the list for the debugger, is wrapped in a [`!FEATURE_PAL`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738402/what-is-feature-pal-compiler-directive-means-in-net-4-source-code) region. So it is very possible that something OS specific lets it get tracked.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ah-ha! From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/26/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview.aspx

    In Windows 8.1 Preview, the OS has an understanding of asynchronous operations and the states that they can be in, which is then used by Visual Studio 2013 preview, in this new window (Tasks)

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it accepted. I would upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/26/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview.aspx

```
In Windows 8.1 Preview, the OS has an understanding of asynchronous operations 
and the states that they can be in, which is then used by Visual Studio 2013 preview, 
in this new window [Tasks]
```

Given that @ScottChamberlain confirmed that Tasks window in Visual Studio works on Win8.1 and not on Win7, that seems to be the problem.