# Debugging asynchronous ASP.NET WebAPI controller shows "No tasks to display" in Tasks window

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

I'm trying to debug some asynchronous code using the Tasks window (Debug -> Windows -> Tasks), but when I break on a line within an async method using a breakpoint the Tasks window shows "No tasks to display".

My project is a WebAPI project running in IIS Express on a Windows 8.1 machine in Visual Studio 2013.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638563/vs2013-debug-windows-tasks-no-tasks-to-display) which is very similar, but the answer given here is that it needs to run on a windows 8.1 machine rather than Windows 7... but I *am* running 8.1!

I've tried creating a basic console application, setup a very simple asynchronous app and debugging that, and it works perfectly ok there... so what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it work in my WebAPI project?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an OWIN self-hosted application.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Miral: No, sorry... I think I eventually just found the bug I was looking for without this and moved on... it would just have been easier had I got this to work.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same (I had a deadlock, which are always fun to track down without hints).  Wish this had worked though.

Comment: I wonder if this is even possible. See [link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10537782-allow-viewing-async-tasks-in-asp-net-applications)

Comment: Keep in mind that async/await behaves differently in a console application than it does in Web API (no synchronization context in a console application), so that's not really a valid comparison. (That's one of the major "gotchas" in async/await). Can you post the problematic code?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Visual Studio 2017 15.6 or above can solve this problem.

This problem was a known issue and it can be found here [on Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/74759/tasks-window-always-shows-no-tasks-to-display.html) The status tag confirms that **the issue was fixed in Visual Studio 2017 15.6 preview 1 and Visual Studio 2017 15.6**. I was trying to find an official announcement for fixing this issue in the official release note and their official blog but found none.

[Visual Studio Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017-version-15-6-preview/), [Official Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.6#-visual-studio-2017-version-1560)

With the latest version, this should be no longer an issue.