# Why the Parallel Stacks doesn't show any task?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, task-parallel-library

I'm debugging a application that makes heavy use of the TPL using the `async` and `await` pattern for working, but when I pause the application the **Parallel Stacks** window shows only the following message:

*No tasks to display. LoadSymbols*[image]

I'm 100% sure that there are multiple tasks running because when I set a breakpoint in one of the code that is running on parallel this is hitted.

I read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638563/vs2013-debug-windows-tasks-no-tasks-to-display) in where the problem was that this debugger feature only worked on windows 8.1 and up, but I have:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Community 2015
- This is a WPF application

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TaskCompletionSource`-based tasks do not show up in the Visual Studio task debugging features. Also, while an async IO is in progress there is no thread busy processing the IO. This in combination means that you cannot find out what async IO work is running at the moment.

This is one of the key drawbacks of async IO. You cannot pause the debugger to see what's going on and you cannot use profiling tools.

(Answer valid as of VS2015. Maybe this will change.)