# Visual Studio 2015 - how to get a list of Tasks from async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Using the VS2015 Debugger, how can I access a list of all Tasks in a particular context?  For example, in the below SAMPLE, I would like to see that there are two Tasks: "Test" and "TestAsync".  So far, I have only been able to see the first one - I can't see implicit Tasks from async methods.

### PARALLEL STACKS/TASKS WINDOWS (Windows 8.1+)

*updated 6/9/16*

The "Parallel Stacks" and "Tasks" windows in VS2015 are an easy way to do it, but there is an undocumented limitation that prevents them from working in Windows 7 (which is what I am using).

In Windows 7, they will only list explicitly created "Task" objects. For example, in the below SAMPLE, I can see one Task for "Test", when I am expecting two Tasks ("Test" and "TestAsync")

According to [MSDN Using the Tasks Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998369.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396%20MSDN):

> In managed code, you can use the Tasks window when you work with System.Threading.Tasks.Task objects or with the await and async keywords

However, in Windows 7, it will not work with async/await. This is further reinforced in [VS2013 Debug/Windows/Tasks: "No tasks to display"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638563/vs2013-debug-windows-tasks-no-tasks-to-display), which suggests that this is an OS issue, and it would work if I was running Windows 8.1 or later. I have not tested in Windows 10.

### USING OBJECT INSPECTION?

If I can't use "Parallel Stacks", are there some manager objects I can inspect to get an enumerable list of Tasks?

For example, if you put a breakpoint in the async method for a WPF application, and look at the callstack, you may see

- SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation
- DispatcherOperation
- ExecutionContext

I've tried inspecting the "Task t2" object but haven't found anything useful yet. E.g.
 - Task.ExecutingTaskScheduler is null
 - Task.CapturedContext is not null but doesn't have any useful references
 - Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher._queue might be useful?
 - TaskScheduler.Current.ScheduledTasks is empty

### SAMPLE

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskWatchSimple
{
    class Program
    {
        static Task t1;
        static Task t2;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            t1 = new Task(Test);
            t1.Start();
            t2 = TestAsync();

            Debugger.Break();
        }

        static async Task TestAsync()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

### ENVIRONMENT

- VS2015 Update 2
- Windows 7 64-bit
- .NET 4.5.2 (also tried 4.6.1)